# Libparted error "partitions 5. 7, 8...128 on /dev/sda have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change"

Tags: fedora, gparted, gpt

When opening GParted on my Fedora 32 system, I receive the following message:

[image]

I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong here. The system boots fine. I tried running fsck (via adding file /forcefsck and rebooting) but it didn't change anything.
EDIT: Partition table is GPT, that's probably relevant eh.

Comment: if you're running 5.8.8/5.8.9 kernel you might be experiencing this https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/67891

Comment: @frostschutz I'm on kernel 5.8.8-200.fc32.x86_64 so yes that could definitely be the case. I hope that fix is incorporated into the production kernel soon, this is really annoying!

Comment: the fix is in 5.8.10 - in case of ArchLinux they patched it in 5.8.9. Not sure regarding Fedora kernel builds, not using that distro, sorry.

Comment: fedora seems to be tracking the bug here - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1878858 - and it sounds like the fix already got pushed to their stable repo. Did you run another update recently?

Comment: comment from their bugtracker """This is a bug in kernel (or behaviour change in kernel that breaks parted), it should be fixed in 5.8.9-200.fc32.x86_64""" https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1880203#c1

Answer (score 0):

If you have write permission to the device, but do not have the capability (root usually has this), to update the partition table, then it will not be updated.

Some common causes:

- not being root.
- running in a container.
- being root, but not having the capability (using a capability segregation system).

Solution:
The message says reboot. While this is a pain, it should work. It won't stop it happening again, but it will fix it for now (if using a container, then you have to reboot the host).

Other causes:

Some comments mention a bug. It could be the cause, but I see nothing in the question that indicate a bug. (except the exact match of the error message: that list of numbers)

However I have seen in some partition tools (I think gparted), that it won't let you get this far if you are not root (I consider this a bug, the devs don't). But this could be circumvented see the remaining common causes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is [the bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1878858) mentioned in the comments. I remember when this happened and this happened even without doing changes to the partition table, (g)parted printed this on "read" actions too. I also doubt that Falador has 128 partitions (max for GPT, also something specific to this bug, (g)parted printed this for partitions that don''t exist, 5 to 128 in this case). Your answer is generally correct, but I think only kernel/parted update will help in this case.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny I agree, the error message being un-eerily like the one in the bug report, number of partitions, only errorring on non existent partitions (is this the case). So  probably the bug.